# Dynamic innerHTML and the review process

Tags: firefox-addon

We are attempting to upload our addon to the Mozilla "addon" store.  We have received a warning about using `innerHTML`. Is this a deal breaker in the review process? I don't want to submit it yet without maybe getting some feedback on this.

> innerHTML should not be set dynamically
>
> Warning: Due to both security and performance reasons, innerHTML 
>   should not be set using dynamic values. This can lead to security
>   issues or fairly serious performance degradation.

I use innerHTML a few times in my script just to change the wording of links that are created by the addon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My experience is that generally they prefer you resolve the warnings, unless there is a good reason for an exception.  In this case, you can easily use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) API instead.  Probably, [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The real reason is that, besides security holes, this has performance impact in the sense that it sometimes forces a rebuild of the DOM tree or whatnot, so it's actually better for performance to not use `innerHTML`.